# Create keypath based on parameter

Tags: swift, keypaths

I got this code:

```
class Person {
    let age = 0
}

func createKeyPath() {
    let ageKeyPath = \Person.age // Works
}

func createKeyPath(from: ???) { // What can I place here to make it compile?
    let ageKeyPath = \from.age
}
```

I got generic classes and I need to create keypaths on a generic concrete type (like Person), but I am not sure how I can create keypaths based on a parameter. I tried:

```
func createKeyPath(from: Person.Type) {
    let ageKeyPath = \from.age
}
```

But it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a playground example (basically you are going to need to constrain the generic so that the compiler can be sure the KeyPath you are looking for actually exists on that generic type):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

protocol Ageable {
    var age: Int {get}
}

class Person: Ageable {
    let age = 0
}

func createKeyPath<SomeAgeable: Ageable>(from: SomeAgeable) -> KeyPath<SomeAgeable, Int> {
    return  \SomeAgeable.age
}

let p = Person()
let keyPath = createKeyPath(from: p)
print(p[keyPath: keyPath])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create keypaths on a generic concrete type (like Person), but I am not sure how I can create keypaths based on a parameter.

A string is used for the keypath parameter in methods that handle keypaths, like `value(forKeyPath:)`.

Comment: This defeats compile-time safe keypaths, something I really like. I would expect I can pass in Person as a parameter and later on create keypaths in the method it gets called in. I don't want to type in raw property names.